# Windows command line time limit

Tags: windows, command-line, timeout

How might I go about limiting the execution time of a command line program in Windows? I know in Linux there is `timeout`/`timelimit` available, but I have been unable to find similar utilities for Windows.

Comment: It's probably best to write a Powershell or Python script to do this.

Answer (score 10):

```
start yourprogram.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10
taskkill /im yourprogram.exe
```

If you put this in notepad and save it as `.bat` it will create a batch file that will do this.

I have used 10 seconds as an example, just tweak to your needs.

Also, if you are using Vista or above you can scrap the `ping` line and use the much easier `timeout` command in it's place

```
timeout /t 10
```

Comment: How would this handle arguments and multiple instances of yourprogram? It would be nice if start would return a PID, but no such luck...

Comment: You can pass arguments with `start yourprogram.exe yourarguments`. Yeah it would, `taskkill` has an option to kill by PID but you would have to extract it from `tasklist` first based on name, which is back at square one if you have multiple instances. This is just a limitation of cmd.

Comment: +1 Using ping as the timout timer is a funny idea :)

Comment: Append `> NUL` to the `ping` command to squash it's output.

Answer (score 4):

As I know there seems no such a function exist, but I think it's doable if you make it run as a windows task via Task Scheduler, from there you can set a limitation of execution, the setting named as: **Stop the task if it runs longer than:**, you can get more detail from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722178.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you can be bothered with using PowerShell:
`$app = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath 'notepad' -ArgumentList 'test.txt'` will start notepad with an argument of test.txt (you can separate multiple arguments by `,`.

`Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` will sleep for 10s.

Either `$app.Kill()` or `taskkill /PID $app.Id` will kill the started application.

If you prefer a cmd solution that will only call PowerShell to start the process and then store it's PID in a variable:
`for /F %A in ('powershell -Command "(Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath 'notepad' -ArgumentList 'test.txt').Id"') do set PID=%A` (when called from a .bat/.cmd you have to use `%%A` instead of `%A`). You can then use @BaliC's methods of timing out and `taskkill /PID %PID%` to kill the started application.

Comment: this still waits for the full 10 seconds. `Wait-Job` or `Wait-Process` will be much better because it'll return immediately if the command exits early

Answer (score 3):

**Solution :**

In windows it needs to make three batch files

**process.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
start   /b cm.bat
start  cmd.exe /c run.bat
EXIT
```

**cm.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
a.exe < input.txt > out.txt
taskkill /im a.exe /f
taskkill /im cmd.exe /f
EXIT
```

**run.bat**

```
@ECHO off
timeout /t 5
taskkill /im a.exe /f 
taskkill /im cmd.exe /f

EXIT
```

Now Run process.bat . it will start both cm.bat and run.bat simultaneously/parallely. When a.exe from cm.bat terminates; cm.bat kills run.bat and thus it will work as ubuntu timeout.

Comment: The best answer. However it would be even better to use custom window title: `start "a.exe killer" cmd.exe /c run.bat` together with `taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq a.exe killer" /f` and so on

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier in PowerShell than cmd because there's a [`Wait-Job` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) for this. You can run your app like this

```powershell
$timeout = 60
$job = sajb { yourprogram.exe }; if (-not ($job | wjb -T $timeout)) { spjb $job }
```

But it's easier to put it into a function in the profile for reuse by running `notepad $PROFILE` in PowerShell and paste this snippet

```powershell
Function Invoke-WithTimeOut {
    Param (
        [int]$timeout,
        [scriptblock]$script
    )

    $job = Start-Job $script
    $done = $job | Wait-Job -TimeOut $timeout
    if (-not $done) { Stop-Job $job }
}
```

Then you can use it in any PowerShell sessions. For example to run `yourprogram.exe` with 40s timeout

```powershell
Invoke-WithTimeOut 40 { yourprogram.exe }
```

This works even when there are multiple instances of the same app running, unlike the other `taskkill` solutions. Besides it'll return immediately if the command exits before time out so you don't have to wait the full time

You can replace [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.3) with [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.3) for better performance but in normal cases they don't make a difference

If cmd is really needed then you can call this from a batch file

```powershell
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -C "Invoke-WithTimeOut 40 { yourprogram.exe }"
```

From  Windows 10 (1607+) there's also a [native solution](https://ss64.com/nt/scriptrunner.html)

```powershell
ScriptRunner.exe -appvscript yourprogram "with" "args" -appvscriptrunnerparameters -wait -timeout=60
```

If you change `Start-Job`/`Start-ThreadJob` and `Wait-Job` to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) then the result will be the same as the ScriptRunner solution above